# James Munkres' Topology: Clarification in the proof that an imbedding implies the existence of a compactification in a compact Hausdorff space.

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Below is an excerpt from James Munkres' *Topology*:

> [image]

> [image]

**My Question**: I don't quite follow the highlighted texts. If $Y$ is a topology after the said topologization, then isn't any subset of $Y$ automatically a subspace, including $X$? The homeomorphism $h$ here seems irrelevant. Any clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: He means the topological space $X$ with its original topology. Why does that agree with the subspace topology $X$ inherits from $Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that $X$ is a subset of $Y$.  But what the highlighted sentence means is that $X$ with its original topology is the same as $X$ with the subspace topology induced from $Y$; in other words, the original topology and the subspace topology induced from $Y$ coincide on $X$.

Comment: @DickGrayson The whole proof boils down to "transport of structure", if you know what that is.

Comment: I see. But then there would be a potential problem: there might be an open set $V$ in $Y_0$ such that $V=h(W)\cup k(B)$ for some $W\subset X$ that is NOT open in $X$ and some $B\subset A$. Then by the topologization, $H^{-1}(V)$ would be open in $Y$ by the declaration and therefore $W$ would be open in the new induced subspace topology $X$ (since $W=H^{-1}(V)\cap X$) but not in the original one, thus the two topologies fail to coincide.

Comment: @DickGrayson That could not happen.  Because $V$ open in $Y_0$ implies that $V\cap X_0$ is open in $X_0=h(X)$.  Since $h$ is a homeomorphism between $X$ and $h(X)$, we then have $h^{-1}(V\cap X_0)$ open in $X$, but that set is the same thing as your $W$.

Comment: You are right. Thank you!